# Spring Boot JPQL not working for Specific Condition

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I am facing issue related to JPQL in spring boot application. I am facing issue "Invalid parameter index! You seem to have declare too little query method parameters!" . Not able to fetch record by UserName and Client Code. Please check my below code snippet for Spring Boot Application.

Bean Class UserClients.Java.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usersclients")
public class UserClients implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long ID;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userName", referencedColumnName = "userName")
    private Users user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "clientCode", referencedColumnName = "code")
    private Clients client;
}
```

Repository Class UserClientsRepository

```
@Repository
public interface UserClientsRepository extends CrudRepository<UserClients, Long> {

@Async
@Query(value = "from UserClients userCli join userCli.user user  join userCli.client client  where user.userName= ?0 and client.clientCode= ?1", nativeQuery = true)
UserClients fetchRecordByUserNameClient(String userName,String clientCode);

}
```

Service Class UserClientsService

```
@Service
public class UserClientsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserClientsRepository userClientsRepository;


    public UserClients fetchRecordByUserNameClient(String username, String clientCode) {
        return userClientsRepository.fetchRecordByUserNameClient(username, clientCode);
    }

}
```

Controller Class AuthenticationController

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/token")
public class AuthenticationController {


    @Autowired
    private UserClientsService userClientsService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/android-generate-token", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ApiResponse<AuthToken> loginActivity(@RequestBody LoginUserDto loginUser) {
        try {
            final UserClients userClients= userClientsService.fetchRecordByUserNameClient(loginUser.getUsername(), 
                    loginUser.getClient());
            if(userClients == null) {
                return new ApiResponse<>(401, "failed", null);
            }
            return new ApiResponse<>(200, "success", new AuthToken(token, user.getUserName()));
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            return new ApiResponse<>(401, e.getMessage(), null);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is wrong.

1) you have set native = true that means you want to use SQL. But the query looks like HQL

2) you should use named parameters.

Additionally I'm not sure what you want to achieve with @Async. This query will never run asynchrous without return a Future object.

So your query should look like:

```
@Repository
public interface UserClientsRepository extends CrudRepository<UserClients, Long> {

    @Async
    @Query("select userCli from UserClients userCli join userCli.user user join userCli.client client "+ 
           "where user.userName= :userName and client.clientCode= :clientCode")
    Future<UserClients> fetchRecordByUserNameClient(String userName,String clientCode);

}
```